# How to combine file to a folder path in NUnit C#

Tags: c#, linux, nunit, facebook-c#-sdk

I've written a test using NUnit Testcase. I've defined the file name 'irm_xxx_tbbmf_xu.csv.ovr' and what data I expect that file to output.

I've defined a variable `processFilePath` containing the location of where that file will be and the file name within a NUnit `TestCase` attribute parameter.

My question is the way I've written the `processFilePath` how can I write it so it finds the file name from the `[NUnit.Framework.TestCase]` as I expect it to. As currently it's not combining the two. And will the `Assert.AreEqual` work the way I've written it.

```
[NUnit.Framework.TestCase("irm_xxx_tbbmf_xu.csv.ovr", "6677,6677_6677,3001,6")]
[NUnit.Framework.TestCase("irm_xxx_tbbmf_xxx.csv.ovr", "6677,22,344")]
public void ValidateInventoryMeasurement(string path, string expected)
{
    var processFilePath = "/orabin/product//inputs//actuals/";
    var actual = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor.
        RunLinuxcommand("cat " + path);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running your test?  It would be best if you did that and then asked question about problems instead of asking about potential problems.

Comment: @StuartLC How would i append it?

Comment: @JOpenDock Use `Path.Combine`

Comment: @StuartLC How would path.combine work with my example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you aren't actually using the path when locating the file you want to compare in the test. 
There are any number of ways to combine file paths - @juharr's suggestion of using `Path.Combine` is best practice (especially on Windows), but you could really use any technique for string concatenation - I've used string interpolation to do this below.

```
using System; // Other usings 
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyTests
{
....


[TestCase("irm_xxx_tbbmf_xu.csv.ovr", "6677,6677_6677,3001,6")]
[TestCase("irm_xxx_tbbmf_xxx.csv.ovr", "6677,22,344")]
public void ValidateInventoryMeasurement(string path, string expected)
{
    const string processFilePath = "/orabin/product/inputs/actuals/";
    var actual = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor
                       .RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath}{path}");

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

**Notes**

- I'm assuming that the System Under Test is `Common.LinuxCommandExecutor`
- The `processFilePath` path is constant and can be turned into a `const string`
- I've cleaned out the [double slashes //](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11965/230735)
- You can add a using `NUnit.Framework` at the top of your NUnit .cs file and then you won't need to repeat the full namespace `NUnit.Framework.TestCase`, i.e. just `[TestCase(..)]`
- You may need to watch for extraneous whitespace on the output of the `cat`. In which case, you could consider:

```
  Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.Trim());
```